# Can't login to Django admin using correct username and password

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-admin, gunicorn

I have deployed a Django application on [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) using `ngnix`, `gunicorn` and a `Postgresql` database. Everything works just fine and when I run `python manage.py syncdb` and I'm able to create a user which populates my DB nicely.

Problem I'm having is that when I try to login to the Django admin interface I get prompted that I'm using the wrong username and/or password. I'm pretty sure the credentials are right as I have tried setting up the db multiple times.

Any ideas why Django thinks I'm inputing the wrong user info?

Thanks!

**SETTINGS.py** looks like

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.admin',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'qvido.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'qvido.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydbname',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass!',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'ROOT': '',
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = '/webapps/django-env/static/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**WSGI.py** looks like

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "qvido.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**EDIT**

Ok, I aslo tried doing `python manage.py dbshell` and the `select * from auth_user;` I see the user I've created but still can't log in with it. So strange.

Comment: can you again try "python manage.py createsuperuser" for create a super user. and then try to login with new username and password.

Comment: still getting the same prompt when trying to log in with the new superuser. The record is created in the database.

Comment: are you using default django auth or you have modify django authentication?

Comment: Default. Haven't modified anything.

Comment: can you please add your setting.py code so we figure out.

Comment: @Yogesh update the question with settings.py

Comment: Can you connect directly to the database and make sure your user is really created?

Comment: I have update the order of install apps as well your SECRET_KEY is nat valid in setting.py after this new setting please run syncdb again

Comment: @Torsten I've connected to the database and my users are created.

Comment: @Yogesh my secret key is correct, I just didn't want to share it here :) I'll try your changes now.

Comment: @Yogesh the changes in settings.py didn't have a effect.

Comment: I think your problem is something different, Your wsgi configuration would show different app than your current app. Try to run your server with `./manage.py runserver` and test it. If it works you have a mistake on wsgi configuration.

Comment: @scriptmonster yep that seems to be the problem. What could the problem in my wsqi be?

Comment: @Ismailp since we share same name :D, I believe you have multiple instance of your code and you are running wrong one via wsgi

Comment: @scriptmonster I don't see how I can have several instances of the code running and I don't see anything strange with my wsgi setup. Where should I look in order to investigate this further? Thanks :)

Comment: @Ismailp it's to hard to say how to investigate from remote. We could start a chat room and discuss by doing some tests.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46023/discussion-between-ismailp-and-scriptmonster)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I found the answer to why this was happening and indeed @scriptmonster was correct.

When I installed Django, Gunicorn etc. in my virtual-env I used sudo pip install which installed these outside of my virtaul-env.

I ran `sudo chown -R myuser:myuser /webapps/myenv` and then ran `pip install django` and `pip install gunicorn` again and everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 6):

I apologize for the late answer, but I believe that this may be useful to someone.

I was having this same issue. After reading all of the comments to the original question, I was able to figure out what had happened.

During development, I had switched databases from an old test db to a new one which included all of the required tables rather than just changing the existing db. I had only changed the `settings.py` file to update the location of the new db, and did not touch the `wsgi.py` file. After migrating to the new db and removing the old file from the project, my admin user did not exist within the new database.

Based on comments by @Torsten Engelbrecht and the OP, all I needed to do was run the command suggested by @Alen thomas to make it functional again:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

At this point I was able to set up the same admin account I'd used before, since it no longer existed. Now it all works fine. It might seem a little silly, but it pays to check the

Comment: Exactly! when you update the database , you have to create the superuser again!